# "Definition mx.utils:Base64Encoder could not be found" in Flex Builder 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to edit an existing AS3 application (which was built using Flash Develop) in Flex Builder 3.

The application uses Base64Encoder (using "import mx.utils.Base64Encoder"). This compiles without problems in Flash Develop but trying to build it in Flex Builder 3 (Mac version) gives an error:

"Definition mx.utils:Base64Encoder could not be found"

Indeed when using code completion (ctrl + space) in flex, on "import mx.utils." only 4 utils are shown in the list.

I've tried this using the Flex 3.2.0 sdk that came with Flex Builder 3 and the Flex 3.5.0 sdk which I downloaded from the adobe website.

Does anyone know why this might be? and how I could resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I've fixed this by adding 'framework.swc' to my library build path.

Instructions:

1. Right-click project and select 'properties'
2. Select Actionscript Build Path
3. Select 'Library Path' tab
4. Click 'Add SWC...' button
5. Enter [path to your sdk]/frameworks/libs/framework.swc
6. Click 'OK' to add swc
7. Click 'OK' to close properties
8. Re-build your project

Comment: After I type import I don't see frameworks in the list of libs

Comment: Seems counterintuitive that mx.utils would be located in framework.swc, not mx.swc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [SDK]/frameworks/libs/rpc.swc file from Flex SDK

Answer (score 0):

It's probably borrowed from the Flash class lib rather than the Flex one. There are plenty of base64 implementations out there that you could substitute.